# what kind of ftp server in linux let me to have different user credentials rather than linux built in users?

Tags: linux, ftp

I'm looking for a ftp server which let me have different user credentials management rather than using linux built-in user/pass ?

Comment: Are you wanting to have specific ftp-only users, or are you wanting to use an existing user database - eg authenticating against an LDAP database?

Comment: yes , exactly I want to use existing user database or LDAP.

Comment: @austinpowers: when asking for help it's very much better to tell us what you really want. Then we can give you better answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[ProFTPD](http://www.proftpd.org/) and [VsFTPD](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html) can both be configured to take virtual users. Both can be configured to use alternate passwd files, mysql databases, LDAP etc for managing user credentials. Both should be available from a repo near you.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by using a custom `pam.d` file for your FTP application, pointing it to an alternate set of files in place of the actual passwd/shadow set.

One such PAM module that does this is [`pam_fshadow`](http://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/software/pam-modules/manual/html_chapter/fshadow.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague, but I guess you mean if you can have an FTP server which does not use system accounts at all, but isolated accounts.

Well, then you have many choices.

[ProFTPd](http://proftpd.org/) lets you store user information in LDAP or SQL, not depending on PAM at all. ProFTPd can also use `pam_ldap` or `pam_mysql` without any dependancy to your system accounts.

[Pure-FTPd](http://pureftpd.org/) is similar and even more lightweight.

You can also configure `vsftpd` to use LDAP/SQL with `pam_ldap` or `pam_mysql` without depending on system accounts at all.

And, are you sure you need `FTP` and not `SFTP` these days?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [CrushFTP](http://www.crushftp.com).  It supports many OSs and many protocols. You can use a separate user database. Way too many features to list here but there is a free trial.  Support, even during trial is excellent.